# Excel VBA limit worksheet color palette

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I am currently working on an idea to organize better a workbook. In my team we are using a workbook with many TABS in a progressive job, split in several phases. In each phase we will be using different TABS.

We usually color the worksheet TAB to indicate whether if it has been done or not. I would to customize the color index for the worksheet TAB so only 3 different colors remain available (let's say green, black, white).

It is critical to limit the color palette so users won't pick up other color and therefore a TAB analysis by colors (and standardization) can be carried out.

I've been researching this concept for a few days ([changing color options](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm)).
I found what I though it was the solution ([official Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288412)) but is not working (after changing all the colors, in the worksheet, it shows the normal palette).

Any idea if is possible to code customization of color TAB? or how does really works the Microsoft "changing standard color" ?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround

You could catch bad colored tabs before exiting the workbook by placing this code in ThisWorkbook code pane

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case sht.Tab.ColorIndex
        Case 1, 2, 4 '(1=Black, 2=White, 4=Green) see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx
            ' ok
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Sheet '" & sht.name & "' has tab not properly coloured" _
                  & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please have its tab coloured with any of the following colors:" _
                  & vbCrLf & vbTab & "- Green" _
                  & vbCrLf & vbTab & "- Black" _
                  & vbCrLf & vbTab & "- White", vbCritical
            Cancel = True
    End Select
Next sht

End Sub
```

which will force the user to color properly ALL tabs for the event handler to let him close the workbook finally!

Comment: Hello!
Yeah I have a couple of workarounds in mind.. but as you may know, anything that doesn't make it flow smoother is a pain in the a** for the users... If I don't find a radical solution as "You have option A or B, that's all" and, in the same time, not causing troubles or prompting windows to the user.. I will not be able to implement anything :S I keep surfing the net! If I find anything close I will post it

Comment: @Charlie did you find any solution?

Comment: I swear I tried for a week :D not a chance...
Currently I'm working on custom Ribbons... it came to me the idea of disabling the color pallete and then adding some button customized to perform this... too much trouble for little reward. And not sure if the users will agree...